# How to fix error creating event grid subscription for a Azure Function Core hosted on Linux?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an Azure Function Core running on a Linux consumption plan running in WestUS.  The function seems to be running OK - I had a previous .NET Standard 2.0 version of the same function running OK in Azure. However, when I try to create a subscription to an Event Grid Topic I get the following error:

> Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://insysfunctiongetweathercore.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."}

I am using an EventGridTrigger so should not have to do anything to handle validation - this *should* happen automatically:

```
public static async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
```

Any ideas on what I might need to do differently when the function is hosted in Linux consumption plan?

EDIT

Here's a screenshot of the Create Event Subscription Form with error:

[image]

and the resulting JSON:

```
{
"name": "InSysWeatherPull",
"properties": {
    "topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/InergySystemsWest/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/Topics/InSysEventGridWest",
    "destination": {
        "endpointType": "WebHook",
        "properties": {
            "endpointUrl": "https://insysfunctiongetweathercore.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=ProcessWeatherRequest&code=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "includedEventTypes": [
            "weather-zip-request"
        ],
        "advancedFilters": []
    },
    "labels": [],
    "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema"
}
```

}

Comment: How do you create a subscription to an Event Grid Topic? Did you directly `Add event grid subscription` in function panel?

Comment: That's right... When I click create on the Create Event Subscription form I get the error.

Comment: Not able to repro it(linux consumption plan c# EventGridTrigger), is it a consistent error on your side?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the form I filled in.  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I've tried deleting the function and re-creating it, and trying again.  Same result... Note that the App Service Plan (WestUSLinuxDynamicPlan) is not in the same resource group as the Event Grid, but this hasn't proved a problem before.

Comment: I might have something.  If I click on the link used for validation (https://insysfunctiongetweathercore.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=ProcessWeatherRequest&code=..........................) I get "cannot find function: 'ProcessWeatherRequest'", despite the function name being correct.

Comment: And something else:  the auto-generated function.json is {"generatedBy":"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions-1.0.24","configurationSource":"attributes","bindings":[{"type":"eventGridTrigger","name":"eventGridEvent"}],"disabled":false,"scriptFile":"../bin/InSysFunctionGetWeatherCore.dll","entryPoint":"InSysFunctionGetWeatherCore.MainFunction.Run"}   ... Note that the entryPoint refers to MainFunction.Run, and not ProcessWeatherRequest.Run.

Comment: Even if I rename the function back to the default MainFunction, the the validation link fails.

Comment: To verify the entryPoint, it's in the format of `namespace.class.methodName`. If the function is in a class called `MainFunction`, it's expected.  `cannot find function: 'ProcessWeatherRequest'` might be the cause as I see 400 bad request instead of not found, when accessing my webhook url in browser.

Comment: The function may fail to be deployed somehow. Not very practical, but I recommend you to delete all resources(Function app, app service plan, storage) related and try to create a new Function app with a different name.